# Regular expression - preg_replace - replace specific content inside paragraph

Tags: php, regex

Im trying to implement functionality wich will replace only specific word between `<p>` tags

For example:

```
<p>this is word i need to replace</p>
```

In this case "word" will be replaced with some other word (but only inside `<p>` tags)

Currently im using:

```
preg_replace("/\b$keyword\b/", $replaceWord, $content, 2);

$content - contains all html
$keyword - word wich need to be replaced in that content
$replaceWord - word wich we want to use instead $keyword
```

But this logic above will replace also keywords wich are not inside paragraph.
How its possible to update this regex, so it replaces only words inside paragraphs?

NOTE: Please make a note that i cannot use [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: You might check around this site for the expert opinion on parsing HTML via regex. You'll find some rather strong arguments against doing so.

Comment: use the full php [DOM](http://php.net/dom) instead

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar w/ php, but here it is in python.  Figured I'd try and help since you were unanswered for a while. You can see that I'm matching and storing the stuff surrounding the word, and adding that back in w/ my replacement called "new word".  And that it does indeed ignore the word "word" inside the < h1 > tags.

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "<p>this is word i need to replace</p>"
>>> a += "\n<h1>blah blah crud word</h1>"
>>> re.sub("(<p>.*?)word(.*?</p>)","\g<1>new word\g<2>",a)
'<p>this is new word i need to replace</p>\n<h1>blah blah crud word</h1>'
```

Comment: Why would you think posting a Python answer for a PHP tagged question would be helpful to the OP?

Comment: OP obviously knows how to use regex, their problem was a matter of figuring out how to 'word' the regex correctly.  If I say you need to group the surrounding parts and do the replacement, that's all they need to know. Most languages are 90% the same, and most support a very similar set of functionality when it comes to regex. It's better than the 3 comments under the original question which amount to 'just do it our way, even if you may not be familiar with it, because we know exactly what you REALLY need'.